# Online application timestamped by local PC instead of Server

Tags: timestamp-with-timezone

Is there a way to have my online application get the time and date from the user local machine instead of the server it resides on? The point is that there are users in different time zones and it will not make sense to have the standard UTC time stamp on their files. Thanks in advance fo ryour help.

Comment: The answer is unclear. Primarily due to the question being somewhat unclear. The answer is probably "yes", if you have the ability to modify the application, but if not, it's more like "maybe", depending on exactly what the application is and how it was written, but we can't divine that sort of information from the empty space between the lines...

Comment: Thanks. When the user logues in and work on his file, it gets timestamped based on the server the application is running on. What it should do is get timestamped based on the user local zone (EST, CST, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with JavaScript `new Date()`.